# ActiveXobject is not defined, need alternative

Tags: javascript, jsp, activexobject

I need help and suggestions from you.
We have used ActiveXobject for IE support application now we have migrated to Edge now it is not supporting.
sample code as below.

```js
<script>
function callexe(){
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
var cmd='C:\\ABCDE\\viewer.exe';
objShell.run(cmd);
}
</script>
<a href="#execute" onclick="callexe()">Run</a>
```

can any one help me to over come this?

Comment: There isn't an alternative. Depending on the file format, you could find a plug-in for it.